# Facebook like button in iPhone native application

Tags: ios, facebook

This question seem duplicate but problem is that other question are old or not giving answer as my need.

**What I have done:** 
I have integrated facebook for iOS 5 and iOS 6 both and it is sharing on wall properly.

**Problem** 
My application have a UIButton "LIKE" to like my application page on facebook.
I want that if user click on this button he should be able to like that page.

I have search for hours but not able to get any proper solution.

For iOS 6 I get following link of apple iOS 6 site

[iOS 6 with facebook](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/#facebook)

Here in third segment it show an image where app page is open in UIViewController with facebook like button.
and it said that we can open it without leaving our app.

I search but don't find how to open this page in UIViewController as we open dialog for share.

Ask me if you need more information.

Happy to get any kind of help or information.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the app shown by Apple with the Like button integrated (i.e. the App Store) is using a webview to display its content. This button is not something you get from a native code. The reason is that Facebook don't wan't to get Like actions without a user action to trigger it (I heard that from a Facebook guy at the App Day 2012 conference in Paris). And the only way to ensure that is to encapsulate and hide that in an HTML component.

What I would suggest is to instantiate a small webview displaying a page containing only the Like button of the desired page. Let us know if it work! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Mathieu is right, there is no way you can do that with a normal UIButton.

You have to use an iFrame (loaded in a UIWebView) if you want the button to like the page immediately. I did not like this approach as it takes some time for the iFrame to load.
More information can be found here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app

I ended up having a UIButton that opens the Facebook page in Facebook.app or Safari.app. The user has to press the like button manually.

Answer (score 0):

It's just allowed for testing purposes and iOS only.

check this out
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button/